# Felix: Configuring bundle cache location to a temporary folder

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

In windows, I would like to set the bundle cache location of felix to `%TEMP%/myApp`. As far as I know, the `configurations.property` file that takes `org.osgi.framework.storage` will only take felix system properties using `${property}` notation, but not environment variables.

How do I get %TEMP% in there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried this one Windows, but you could set some system property to your Temp, e.g.

```
java -Dsystem.temp=%TEMP% -jar bin/felix.jar
```

and then use that system property in your configuration, like

```
org.osgi.framework.storage: ${system.temp}/myApp
```

Comment: Thanks! This is sort of what I ended up doing. Because I am additionally using install4j, I can use the user's temp folder as an execution parameter.